# How to inject mat dialog into service?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, modal-dialog

Hi I have a service for the Angular material dialog, like this:

```
export class DialogModelService {
  participant: ParticipantInfoDTO;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.participant = route.snapshot.data['participant'];
  }

  openEcheqSelectorDialog(): Observable<any> {
  const dialogRef =     this.dialog.open(EcheqSelectorComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 2em)',
      data: {
        participant: console.log('participantIDTest', this.participant)
      }
    });

    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }
}
```

And now I try it to inject in a component like this:

```
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit  {


  @Input() participant: ParticipantInfoDTO;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, route: ActivatedRoute, private dialogModelService:  DialogModelService) {
    this.participant = route.snapshot.data['participant'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  openEcheqSelectorDialog(){
    this.dialogModelService.openEcheqSelectorDialog().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

and this is the template:

```
  <button mat-raised-button class="button-spacing" (click)="openEcheqSelectorDialog()" i18n>Send echeq</button>
```

And I have the component declard in this module:

```
 @NgModule({
      declarations: [ListComponent, DetailComponent, ExtendedSearchComponent, LoaderComponent, ChangeEmailComponent],
      exports: [LoaderComponent, DetailComponent],


export class ParticipantModule {}
```

But I get this error:

```
DetailComponent.html:9 ERROR Error: No component factory found for EcheqSelectorComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:7754)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:7792)
    at CdkPortalOutlet.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/portal.es5.js.CdkPortalOutlet.attachComponentPortal (portal.es5.js:654)
    at
```

So my question is: what I have to change?

Thank you

I have that. I have put them both in the module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EcheqQuestionComponent,
    EcheqDisplayComponent,
    EcheqViewListComponent,
    EcheqViewItemComponent,
    EcheqSelectorComponent,
    MetaBoxComponent,
    ConfirmDialogComponent,
    StrenumQuestionComponent,
    StrlistQuestionComponent,
    RadioQuestionComponent
  ],
  exports:[
    EcheqSelectorComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    // Angular
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,

    // Angular Material
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,

    // Carapax
    AuthModule,
    ParticipantEcheqRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    EcheqSelectorComponent,
    ConfirmDialogComponent
  ]
})
export class ParticipantEcheqModule { }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the EcheqSelectorComponent as an entryComponent?

Comment: Eh, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Yes, like this:  entryComponents: [EcheqSelectorComponent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is related where `DialogModelService` is provided.

To check if that is the issue, try providing the DialogModelService in the ParticipantEcheqModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EcheqQuestionComponent,
    EcheqDisplayComponent,
    EcheqViewListComponent,
    EcheqViewItemComponent,
    EcheqSelectorComponent,
    MetaBoxComponent,
    ConfirmDialogComponent,
    StrenumQuestionComponent,
    StrlistQuestionComponent,
    RadioQuestionComponent
  ],
  exports:[
    EcheqSelectorComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    DialogModelService
  ],
  imports: [
    // Angular
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,

    // Angular Material
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,

    // Carapax
    AuthModule,
    ParticipantEcheqRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    EcheqSelectorComponent,
    ConfirmDialogComponent
  ]
})
export class ParticipantEcheqModule { }
```

Comment: But, a component cannot be added as a declaration to multiple modules.... And Entrycomponents is deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **EcheqSelectorComponent** inside module's **entryComponents** and **declarations**